# Where are Bacula Client's jobs history file stored?

Tags: macos, backup, centos7, bacula

I'm using Bacula 9.0.6 on a Centos 7 Server and Bacula client (file daemon) 9.0.6 installed with Homebrew on Mac OS ElCapitan. Some days ago Ii did a bad install of Bacula on the server, but the Mac client was yet configured and working at that time. I setted up a password for the client. Then I removed every part of bacula from my server (MySQL database with catalog stored in, too) and reinstalled (compiling source with make). I also (just to be sure to have a clean setted up system) reinstalled the bacula client on Mac (removed using brew and making sure that all the config files were removed). At first sight everything seemed to be fine (default config files, new database created, new random password generated both on the server and on the Mac client).

BUT, then I couldn't connect to client anymore. I setted up different name, different passwords, everything different, but I always got this error message:

```
JobId 0: Fatal error: Unable to authenticate with File daemon at "192.168.0.2:9102". Possible causes:
Passwords or names not the same or
Maximum Concurrent Jobs exceeded on the FD or
FD networking messed up (restart daemon).
For help, please see: http://www.bacula.org/rel-manual/en/problems/Bacula_Frequently_Asked_Que.html
```

After tens of attempts chenging and checking every possible option **I found out that the only way to make Director (server) connecting to client is to set up them with the old password, from the first wrong installation**. I also noticed that when I catch the status of the Client with the bacula console I see all the old jobs ran at the time of the first installation. How can this be possible with new database?

It's like there is some "ghost" data regarding only my Mac Client stored somewhere. But I don't know if it is on server or on the client and have no clue about in which dir I should look for. I have the suspect that is something bounded to the client's IP Address (obviously it is the only thing I couldn't change because of DHCP). **I'd really like to delete all the history files(so that I can set up a new password, and I won't see old jobs) but really got no idea about where to start from.**

Thank you a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you change a password or client name in Bacula you have to reload the Director with reload command (using bconsole) and restart your Bacula client (bacula-fd process). You have to be sure that your bacula-fd process was truly restarted, as I saw many times that the old one was still running using the old config.
Th client history in the form of a few last running jobs info are stored in a file bacula-fd.9102.state in the directory defined at WorkingDirectory configuration parameter. You can safely delete it (when you stop the bacula-fd process), it will be recreated on start.